# Is there a relationship between the energies of the inputs to a convolution and the energy of its output?

Tags: convolution, signal-energy

I want to convolve discrete signals A and B. I can compute their energies beforehand by squaring the samples and summing the squares, but I'm curious if I can compute the energy of the signal I will get if I convolve A and B using their energies (or anything about them really) without even doing convolution? Is there any mathematical relationship there?

Comment: I think the best you can do is to find an upper bound on the energy of $A * B$ -- think in terms of B being a unity-gain filter with a certain bandpass.  Then the most energy that $A * B$ can have is if $A$'s energy is all concentrated in $B$'s bandpass, and the energy of $A * B$ is equal to the energy of $A$.  But if $A$ has energy outside of $B$'s bandpass, $A * B$ will have less energy than $A$.  Trying to turn that intuition into math makes my head explode, however.

Comment: I've added some new bounds.

Comment: Are `A` and `B` knowns? Is it theoretical question or in practice you're trying to preserve some computational efforts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably not an equality directly, but upper bounds. Let us look at the continuous case first, which is easier to derive. There is a [Young's convolution inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_convolution_inequality): with proper integrability conditions ($A$ is $L_p$ integrable, $B$ is $L_q$ integrable), $1\le p,q\le\infty$ and conjugation: $$\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=\frac{1}{r}+1\,.$$

On the one hand then:
$$\|A\ast B \|_r \le c_{p,q} \|A \|_p \|B\|_q$$

for some constant $c_{p,q}$ that can be computed. On the other hand, there are non-zero vectors whose convolution vanishes, see [When does the convolution of 2 signals equal zero?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/30392/15892).
Therefore, knowing something about $A$ and $B$ separately won't get you a precise idea about their convolution: **you can hope for lower and upper bounds, but no equality**. If you are only interested in the  energy of the convolution, set $r=2$.

In the discrete case, with standard or circular convolution, I remember that results were more complicated to derive, but you can hope for inequalities as well (see works of Beckner and related, like [Optimal Young's inequality and its converse: a simple proof](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9704210).

Comment: ha! Beautiful! That's exactly the motivation for *matched filtering*!

Answer (score 1):

```
a = ones(64,1);
b = [1 -1];
c = conv(a,b);
```

In this case, a and b have some non-zero energy while their convolution is exactly zero besides head and tail conditions.

Comment: With circular convolution, I guess

Comment: Not to be picky here, but your variable `c` is NOT all zeros.

Comment: I did say _except_ head and tail conditions, @Hilmar?

Answer (score -1):

We can get exact bounds from cross-domain energy relations. Given a signal $x(t)$ and a kernel $h(t)$ to convolve with, the frequency-domain result is $X(f)H(f)$, and we know from [Parseval-Plancherel's theorem](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Plancherel_theorem) that

$$
||x * h|| = ||XH||.
$$

Suppose

$$
A \leq |H(f)|^2 \leq B
$$
that is, the energy of any frequency of $h$ is bound between $A$ and $B$. Then, multiplying by $|X(f)|^2$, we get

$$
A |X(f)|^2 \leq |H(f)X(f)|^2 \leq B |X(f)|^2
$$

applying integration,

$$
A \int |X(f)|^2 \leq \int |H(f)X(f)|^2 \leq B \int |X(f)|^2
$$

then the theorem

$$
A \int |x(t)|^2 \leq \int |x * h|^2 \leq B \int |x(t)|^2 \\
\Leftrightarrow \\
A||x||^2 \leq ||x * h||^2 \leq B ||x||^2 \\
$$

which is

$$
\boxed{\text{min}(|H(f)|^2) ||x||^2 \leq ||x * h||^2 \leq \text{max}(|H(f)|^2) ||x||^2}
$$

Hence, the energy of convolving with $h$ is bound by the minimum and maximum of energy of any frequency of $h$. Since $x * h = h * x$, one can repeat this argument starting with $X(f)$:

$$
\boxed{\text{min}(|X(f)|^2) ||h||^2 \leq ||x * h||^2 \leq \text{max}(|X(f)|^2) ||h||^2}
$$

This holds in both continuous and discrete domains, where the discrete energy relation is

$$
\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} |x[n]|^2 = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=0}^{N-1} |X[k]|^2
$$

Without going to frequency domain, working with time-domain energies alone, we can't tell much, as the energy can exceed $||x||^2 \cdot ||h||^2$ or even be zero while neither's energy is.

#### Example

We can have $||a|| > 0$ and $||b|| > 0$ while $||a * b|| = 0$:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.fft import fft, ifft

def E(x):
    return np.sum(np.abs(x)**2)

x = np.random.randn(128)
x -= x.mean()
h = np.ones(128)
conv = ifft(fft(x) * fft(h))

assert np.allclose(conv, 0)
print(E(x), E(h), E(conv))
```

```
117.73576304545941 128.0 1.6155871338926322e-27
```

because $\text{min}(||X[k]||^2) = 0$ (the DC bin, due to `x -= x.mean()`). Note, this is for *circular* convolution, but since we can reformulate it as an exact equivalent of linear, one simply needs to account for spectral effects of zero padding to derive a similar relation (and since zeros don't add energy, the upper bound won't change).

#### Empirical validation of bounds

We trial many examples of a constant convolved with complex white noise, compute distances with upper and lower bounds, and report minimum distances for each:

```
def E(x):
    return np.sum(np.abs(x)**2)

np.random.seed(0)
dists_min, dists_max = [], []
N = 1024
for _ in range(1000):
    x = np.ones(N)
    h = np.random.randn(N) + np.random.randn(N)*1j
    xf, hf = fft(x), fft(h)
    
    mn, mx = np.min(np.abs(hf)**2), np.max(np.abs(hf)**2)
    Ex = E(x)
    
    cconv = ifft(xf * hf)
    dists_min.append(E(cconv) - mn*Ex)
    dists_max.append(mx*Ex - E(cconv))

print(np.min(dists_min), np.min(dists_max))
```

```
-9.094947017729282e-13 3.725290298461914e-09
```

The upper bound is always strictly met, while the lower bound fails only within float precision. If both signals are noise, we're much more within bounds.

Comment: I see where you're going with $E(a * b) = \frac{1}{N}E(AB)$, but if you're using $E(\cdot)$ to denote the energy of something, then I'd go with $E(x) = E\left (\mathcal F \{x\}\right)$ by definition, and, hence, $E\left( \mathcal F \{x\} \right) = \frac{1}{N} \left \| \mathcal F \{ x \} \right \|$ -- even if it's a bit more confusing on the surface.

Comment: @TimWescott Is it by definition for DFT? For CFT, we get $1/2\pi$ with $\omega$, though DFT does $2\pi k$ analogous to CFT's $2\pi f$. Question is, is energy _defined_ as $\sum |\text{stuff}|^2$, or it only happens to work out in time domain (if so, what's the actual definition)? I could open a question

Comment: I think it's worth a question.  It does get a bit philosophical, but I think that for signal processing you want the time domain energy to be $\sum | \text{stuff} |^2$ or $\int |\text{stuff}|^2 dt$, and you want the frequency domain energy for a given signal to calculate out to the same number as the time-domain signal.